# how to expose hashicorp vault on ec2 instance

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I am getting this error using command "vault status" 
: Error checking seal status: Get https://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/sys/seal-status: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client

please help me out to solve this issue.
config.json

```
{
  "listener": [{
    "tcp": {
      "address" : "0.0.0.0:8200",
      "tls_disable" : 1
    }
  }],
  "api_addr": "http://<public ip of EC2>:8200",
  "storage": {
  "file": {
    "path" : "/vault-data"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to set VAULT_ADDR environment variable before using "vault" command:

```
export VAULT_ADDR=http://127.0.0.1:8200
```

Please watch [learn.hashicorp.com](https://learn.hashicorp.com/vault/getting-started/dev-server) for more info.

Comment: I have put public IP of my ec2 instead of vault's localhost IP:                                                                                 export VAULT_ADDR=http://<public ip of EC2>:8200